# Sharing resources across uwsgi processes in a flask app

Tags: web, flask, multiprocessing, uwsgi

I have a dictionary in my flask app with is global and contains information of logged in user.

```
globalDict = {}
globalDict[username] = "Some Important info"
```

When a person logs in this globalDict populates and depopulates when user logs out. When I use uwsgi with a single process, obviously there is no problem.

When I use it with multiple processes, sometimes the dictionary turns out to be empty on printing. I guess this is because there are multiple globalDicts across different processes.

How to share globalDict across all processes in my flask application?

P.S. I use only uwsgi for hosting my server and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to `uwsgi` cache.

uwsgi startup

```
uwsgi --cache2 name=mycache,items=100 --ini $conffile
```

write example:

```
uwsgi.cache_update(this_item["sha"], encoded_blob, 0, "mycache")
```

read example:

```
value_from_cache = uwsgi.cache_get(this_item["sha"], "mycache")
```

[More Details](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Caching.html)